# NicEdit wont save HTML

Tags: php, nicedit

I am trying out NicEdit witch is super light weight and easy to install. The problem is when I use NicEdit its working fine changing content in the textarea - but when I save my content there is no HTML tags in the post? Its all in clear text... Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving nicedit textarea content into mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582700/saving-nicedit-textarea-content-into-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you saving with NicEdit?

You can not get the value using "var variable = $("#id").val();" because that will just get the text in the textarea.

NicEdit has a built in ajax save function that you can use. Check out http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/519/FrontPage and click on Saving via Ajax.

Comment: Thanks Aaron this was what I was looking for. 
[nicInstance].saveContent()
Only for nicInstances that are replacing a <textarea>
this method syncs the content of the editor with the textarea value.
This is done automatically if the form with the orginal
<textarea> is submitted.
However, you may want to explitly do the syncing yourself.