# Saving nicedit textarea content into mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, nicedit

I'm sort of a newbie so I would appreciate a very clear explanation, thanks in advance.

I'm using the nicedit textarea on a website, the information to be read could contain:

- Just plain text (user formatted)
- text and images together

I'm using a mysql database and I don't know how to save the content of the textarea in a way that:

- the text can be read from the database without loosing the users    formatting
- the images in the textarea can be stored into the filesystem and reloaded when the text is being read back from the database (and putting the images in the position the user intended).

I'm using php if that's needed information.

I hope someone understands what I'm trying to get, any help is appreciated even if it's suggesting another approach ...

Comment: Hello - Which library are you using to connect to your database ? PDO/mysql/mysqli ?

Comment: hi, i'm using mysqli

Comment: Sry can't help - It seems Content typed in Nicedit is synced into textarea before submitting & module for uploading using imgur to host it. Couldn't get proper formatted text using $_POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to worry about saving the content because NicEdit saves all text & styles in HTML format. That HTML can easily be saved into a Text field in your database.
The problem is that NicEdit does not sync the styling into the original text area, So when you submit the form the content is saved without the styling.

To solve this, you need to explicitly ask NicEdit to save the styling before you submit the form by adding this line:

```
nicEditors.findEditor('<you_textarea_id>').saveContent();
```